# Deploying the java web application. some listenerStart error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have the next problem:
I am trying to deploy an application on my Tomcat 7.0 with jre 6.0...I created a servlet called ListenerTester:

```
    package com.example;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

class ListenerTester extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {

            response.setContentType("text/html");           
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            out.println("text context attributes set by listener<br />");
            out.println("<br />");

            Dog dog = (Dog) getServletContext().getAttribute("dog");

            out.println("The dog`s breed is: " + dog.getBreed());

        }


    }
```

Class dog is a simple class which has only one field String breed and getter and Constructor with the parameter.

Next class is the MyServletContextListener:

```
   package com.example;

import javax.servlet.*;

class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {

        ServletContext sc = e.getServletContext();

        String dogBreed = sc.getInitParameter("breed");
        Dog f = new Dog(dogBreed);      
        sc.setAttribute("dog", f);

    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e) {



    }

}
```

they are in the package called com.example. The top folder of the application is listenerTester.

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
  version="3.0" >  

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ListenerTester</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.ListenerTester</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ListenerTester</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ListenTest.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>breed</param-name>
    <param-value>Sparky</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

The problem is the next - when I try to run it - the browser does not show anything...at all..no mistake or anything.

```
When I look inside the catalina log file:

    08.11.2011 0:23:56 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
08.11.2011 0:23:56 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
08.11.2011 0:23:56 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 331 ms
08.11.2011 0:23:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
08.11.2011 0:23:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.8
08.11.2011 0:23:56 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory listenerTest
08.11.2011 0:23:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
**SEVERE**: Error listenerStart
08.11.2011 0:23:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/listenerTest] startup failed due to previous errors
08.11.2011 0:23:56 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
08.11.2011 0:23:56 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
08.11.2011 0:23:56 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 233 ms
```

Could you please tell me what to do and what the mistake is? What is a listenerStart?

Comment: You need to look at the catalina.out file for a more detailed log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have your classes public instead of package-private.

Comment: Thank you very much - it was the cause of the problem. I checked localhost log - it was written there that Tomcat could not create a ServletContextListener because of the default modifier.